# I can't see cv2.imshow() result in for loop

Tags: python, opencv

I am new for coding. I am trying to make a little project for myself. OpenCV showing template matching result but its seems like i can't crop it or imshow not giving me crop result

Here are my codes:

```
for myfile in files1:
    image = cv.imread(myfile,0)
    template_data.append(image)



for tmp in template_data:
    w, h = tmp.shape[::-1]
    result = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray,myfile,cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    _, _, _, maxLoc=cv.minMaxLoc(result)
    topLeft = maxLoc
    bottom_right = (topLeft[0] + w , topLeft[1] + h)
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb,topLeft, bottom_right,255, 2)
    crop_img = img_rgb[maxLoc[1]:maxLoc[1]+w, maxLoc[0]:maxLoc[0]+h, :]
    cv.imshow("cropped", *crop_img)
    cv.waitKey()
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

remove the `*` in `imshow` , you must pass the image matrix in one argument

```
cv.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
```

[What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. i did like you said but result is same. i see nothing. I put star in file1 path so can it about it?

Comment: @berkayld what is the error? what is your IDE?

Comment: There is no error. I am using Visiual Studio Code. I just want to crop template result and i want to see it but its feels like skiping this code ` cv.imshow("cropped", crop_img)` showing me nothing after that my terminal waiting next command like everything completed. I can see which picture templated  but i cant see crop result. Thank you so much again